# JavaScript Firefox slow animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation

For demonstration purposes provided example I tried to implement animation in which one div follows actual scrollbar in order to get as many changes as possible.

However, animation works really nice on Chrome, pretty well even in IE but it is extremely laggy in Firefox.

I tried with some hardware acceleration tricks like translateZ(0), etc, but with no success for Firefox.

Instead of top I tried to use transform, again, no luck.

Can I expect better performance if I try canvas?

```js
(function () {

  var scrollerElement = document.getElementById('scroller');
  var elementToMove = document.getElementById('toMove');
  
  var scrollerSize = scrollerElement.clientHeight;
  var maxScroll = scrollerElement.scrollHeight - scrollerSize;
  
  var whileAnimate;
  var timeout;
  var delay = 200;
  
  scrollerElement.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    timeout = setTimeout(cancelAnimation, delay);
    
    if (whileAnimate) {
      return;
    }
    
    startAnimation();
    
  });
  
  function cancelAnimation() {
    whileAnimate = false;
  }
  
  function startAnimation() {
    var animationFrame;
    
    whileAnimate = true;
    
    animate();
    
    
    function animate() {
      
      if (!whileAnimate) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
        return;
      }
      
      elementToMove.style.top = (scrollerElement.scrollTop / maxScroll * scrollerSize) + 'px';
      
      animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      
    }
  
  }

})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#scroller {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 20000px;
}

#toMove {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroller">
  
  <div id="toMove"></div>

  <div id="content"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after, if you want some kind of a debounce for the scroll event, here is how you should do it : https://jsfiddle.net/6okL51zj/

Comment: No actually I just want to have for an example this div, following scrollbar really smooth. In Firefox it easily happens that I loose lot's of frames.

And I am using absolute element therefore it should cause repaints but seems like it is doing something, what I didn't expect.

Comment: Well you are mixing `setTimeout` and `requestAnimationFrame`, for I don't know which purpose. You are producing a TypeError by calling `cancelAnimationFrame()` without the animationFrame id, this is probably why you're experiencing some lags on FF. But once again, I think you should rely only on rAF. Your implementation is too complex. If you really want to run a loop 200ms after the last scroll event occured (even if I don't understand why since the position won't have changed), you've to know that there is a time parameter passed as the single argument of called function inside rAF.

Comment: Ps, if you follow the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6okL51zj/), you'll see that the example div does follow the scrollbar really smoothly, in every browser supporting rAF. The update is triggered at the high rate of the scroll event, but blocked by a flag which is only released once per frame, at screen refresh frame rate (avoiding a lot of unnecessary calls and page redraw) and that's what we call a debounce function.

Comment: Yes, you are correct with all points! I tried your way but there is still the same stuff going on. I also failed to mention that I have couple of thousand characters in scrolling area. That can effect am I correct?

Comment: well if you do use `transform` instead of `top`, the repaint shouldn't touch the content of your scrolling div and should be made on the GPU, so no, it shouldn't have too much impact, note that even using `top`, I don't notice any lag on my machine : https://jsfiddle.net/6okL51zj/1/

Comment: Hmm then seems like there is something wrong with my firefox, as I see serious lags in provided link. I am up to date wit browser and using OS X. Anyway, I will try on different machine and reinstalling browser if it helps, somehow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, after reinstalling animation is much smoother. It isn't perfect still, but in so much better shape.